# How apply SSN masking over text input in Flash Builder 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

i want to apply masking over the textinput that need to get SSN from user so How apply SSN masking over text input in Flash Builder 4?

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box way. You'll have to create a custom component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant solution in the long run would be to create a custom component, but it could also be done within an existing `TextInput`. Give the `TextInput` a `change` event that does the following:

```
var s:String=textInput.text.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
textInput.text = s.substring(0,3) + 
    (s.length>3?"-"+s.substring(3,5)+
    (s.length>5?"-"+s.substring(5,9):""):"");
textInput.selectRange(textInput.text.length,textInput.text.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will mask the characters:

`txtInput.displayAsPassword = true;`

Comment: actually i want something like this http://www.flexden.net/content/masked-text-input and want to know how apply this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<s:TextInput displayAsPassword="true" restrict="0-9" maxChars="9"/>` will cause the text to be shown as asterisks when the user is entering it, and will also prevent them from entering more than 9 characters, or any characters that are not numeric, both of which are requirements of SSNs.

Comment: actually i want something like this http://www.flexden.net/content/masked-text-input and want to know how apply this. Thanks